# add CircularImageView in android studio

Tags: android, imageview, android-studio

i'm trying to use CircularImageView in android studio but i get the following errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
       ComponentInfo{com.dazzlebridge.BeautifulAndSlim/com.dazzlebridge.BeautifulAndSlim.RegistrationActivity}:
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error
       inflating class com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
                   at com.dazzlebridge.BeautifulAndSlim.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:55)
                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
                   at com.dazzlebridge.BeautifulAndSlim.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:55)
                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.R$attr.circularImageViewStyle
                   at com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView.<init>(CircularImageView.java:28)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
                   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
                   at com.dazzlebridge.BeautifulAndSlim.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:55)
                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

i used the answer in [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/app_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cover_pic"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/name_bg"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileview_txt_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profileview_txt_age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_right"
                android:background="@drawable/age_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90.0dip"
            android:layout_height="90.0dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileview_img_profile"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/add_pic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

how can i solve this issue

Comment: Can you post the code for `CircularImageView` please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an ImageView to have rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [this CircularImageView](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) library. It's based off the one you're using but optimized for performance with the addition of selector support.

You can easily use it in Android Studio by adding this line to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1.+'
```

Comment: Thanks It works and little bit better than the original.